# Как правильно изъять данные из ListView.getAdapter.getItem(Position)

Tags: java, android

Может риторический вопрос, но не понимаю, как изъять данные из адаптера. К примеру создать пользовательский класс и в него вкинуть данные из адаптера или использовать ключ для изъятия?

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            parent.getAdapter ().getItem (position);
            Object obj =  listView.getAdapter ().getItem (position);

            return false;
        }
    });
    return v;
```

Comment: сделайте экземпляр адаптера полем класса и обращайтесь непосредственно к нему `adapter.getItem()`, а не  получайте его каждый раз из откуда бы ни было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас же передается какая-то коллекция или массив в адаптер? В адаптере этот стек данных сохраняете в переменную? Сделайте в адаптере метод `getItem`, допустим у вас коллекция `data`

```
public Book getBook(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

И потом в слушателе `OnLongClickListener` берите его так

```
Book clickedBook = adapter.getBook(position);
```

Переменная adapter это ваш адаптер)